# SSRS 2008 R2 Chart - Display Chart average and Group average

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have the following requirement for a report.

I have a repeating bar chart within a Tablix region (grouped by individal). On that chart, I need to display the percentage of a value (call it sales) for each month.  So a chart will have a single employee, with a bar for each month, showing the month total sales as a percentage of the grand total sales.  That's the easy part: my expression shows (=Sum(Fields!Sales.Value) / Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "EmployeeChart").

My next requirement is what has me stumped.  I need to display the average Sales Percentage value for each employee as a line (or bar) next to the individual Sales Percentage value.  So for each month, I need to know how the Percentage distribution compares to the group average Percentage.

The end result has one graph repeated for each employee, with a bar series showing the percentage of sales in each month, and a line series (which has the same values in each chart) showing the average sales percentage of that month for all employees.

I've tried the following, and haven't gotten the results I want.

=Avg(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value) / Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "EmployeeChart"), "EmployeeTablix")

I've also tried various combinations of declaring scopes, none of which worked - I can't get it to give me the average of multiple group separations (e.g., SalesMonth and EmployeeTablix) .

Any suggestions?

Comment: UPDATE: I have a workaround that is getting me the results, but it feels quite a lot like a hack and I would prefer a more elegant solution if anyone can offer it.  What I did was add a DataSet to the report, showing the sum of sales grouped by Month.  I then used a UNION statement to show the grand total of sales, with the month set as 13.  To display on my chart, I used =(Lookup(Fields!Month.Value, Fields!Month.Value, Fields!TotalSales.Value, "TotalSales") / Lookup("13", Fields!Month.Value, Fields!TotalSales.Value, "TotalSales")) * 100

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you divide the grand total by total number of months in your chart for a line chart type?

```
=Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "EmployeeChart") / CountDistinct(Fields!Month.Value)
```

... or similar for your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Shew this one is a bit old but I came across it when looking for solution to a related problem I am having with averages shown on a chart.  I thought I can share what I have done as it might be a solution?

I am working on something similar in SSRS.  I have a chart giving total volumes per day of three items for a week.

On the label of each day I have added (Appended) a total of all items on that day.  And under the series (Showing the colours for each item) I have added an average for the week for each item.

Here's an example..

[image]

(My averages are a bit off with only the last average being correct.)

To append this information to the labels of category or series groups in SSRS you need to do the following:

1. Click on the series group you want to edit of the chart.  This will display a little "Chart Data" window listing "Values," "Category Groups" and "Series Groups".
2. Right-click on the item under either Category or Series group that you want to work with and click on "Properties".
3. Click on the *fx* button next to the "Label" field to open the Expression editor.
4. Add the information you want to display separated by "&".  For example: =Fields!Day.Value & "(Tot.: " & SUM(Fields!Matters.Value) & ")"

This example will display the Name of the day with the text " (Tot.: ", the totals for all items on that day and ended off with ")".  As in "Mon (Tot.: 486)".

If you want to list the appended information below the label, then you must add vbcrlf between some &'s.